# Android activity in landscape - with fragment or dialog in portrait and landscape

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, orientation

Im building a camerafunction in my application.

I've implemented the function as an activity with a surfaceview, and the activity is set to landscape only.

Here is my problem:

I have various settings that can be changed from within the view eg. Flashmode, resolution, zoom etc.
Whenever the user selects the spinner, to be presented with the dialog that allows him/her to select between the various options - the dialog is always in landscape.

I'm trying to figure out how to display the dialog in portrait mode if the phone is turned.
I can get the orientation by using the sensormanager, but how to i put that info to use?

Im thinking that maybe i can have fragments within my acticity as an overlay to the surfaceview, and have the fragments rotated accordingly to the current orientation. But how?

Anyways my preferred solution would be to have the spinnerdialog rotate according to the orientation, but as i have set the orientation in the manifest to landscape, so i cant see how this can be achieved.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance